# STL iterator won't work? Can't figure out why

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, constants

I have a class which has one private member:

```
std::set<unsigned long> Sset;
```

And I have a problem  with this function:

Prototype:

```
Set& Union (Set&, Set&);
```

Code:

```
    Set& Set::Union (Set& s1, Set& s2)
{
    set<unsigned long>::iterator a;
    set<unsigned long>::iterator j;

    for (a = s1.Sset.begin(); a!=s1.Sset.end(); ++a)
        for (j = s2.Sset.begin(); j!=s2.Sset.end(); ++j)
            if (*a = *j)
            {
                Sset.insert(*a);
                break;
            }

    return *this;
}
```

I get compiler error expression must be a modifiable lvalue at `*a=*j`

Everything is OK with iterator j, but it won't accept `*a`

Any help, or explanation?
Thanks

Comment: Your naming convention is confusing.

Comment: did you try `if((*a) == (*j))` ?

Comment: I temporarly swapped it because I thought: maybe that will work...

Comment: This function gives the intersection, not the union.

Comment: You do realize there's a `std::set_union()` and friends in the standard library, right?

Comment: No, actually I didn't realize that :). I'm pretty new to STLs, and C++ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to the value pointed to by a `set::iterator`.

Why?

Because **sets keep their elements in whatever order it feels like** (`set`, specifically, is **sorted**) to allow for quick retrieval, so you can't manually tell it where to put elements.

Instead, `insert` the element at the right place.

Having said that -- did you mean to use `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: I know I can't assign to that value, didn't see that I was missing `=`

Answer (score 4):

should you be using `==` in the if statement?

Comment: Yes... I should. After 10+ hours of coding, I can't see straight. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Classic mistakes :-) - comparison requires two equals signs

```
if (*a == *j)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (*a = *j)
```

is an assignment

```
if (*a == *j)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just insert one set into another in one go:

```
std::set<int> s1, s2;

s1.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

Set members are unique, so there's nothing else to worry about.

Comment: Great advice :). Shaved off about 12 seconds of my execution time :)

Comment: @SeeBeen So, did you actually want set union? Your function, while named _union_, computes the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>

...
std::set_union(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end() ... )
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union